# function that performs multisort is not resulting in sorted data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that does multisorting so that the logic can be called multiple times within the code.  However, when called, the results outputted to the console are not sorted - it is exactly the same as `data` that was passed into the function.  I was able to get the code working before it became a separate method (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69243733/convert-while-loop-to-foreach-has-unexpected-result)).  Why isn't the function returning sorted data?

```js
function multisort(data, sortBy) {
    const dataClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    return dataClone.sort((a, b) => {
        let result = 0;
        sortBy.forEach(o => {
            if (result !== 0) return;
            const property = o.property;
            result = o.direction *
                (
                     a[property] > b[property] ? 1 :
                    (a[property] < b[property] ? -1 : 0)
                );
        });
        return result;
    });
}

const students = [
    {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Appletree',
        grade: 12
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Mighty',
        lastName: 'Peachtree',
        grade: 10
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Kim',
        lastName: 'Appletree',
        grade: 11
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Shooter',
        lastName: 'Appletree',
        grade: 12
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Peter',
        lastName: 'Peachtree',
        grade: 12
    }
    ];

const sortBy = [
    {
      prop:'grade',
      direction: -1
    },
    {
      prop:'lastName',
      direction: 1
    }
];

const sortedStudents = multisort(students, sortBy);
console.log(students);
console.log(sortedStudents);
```

Comment: You use `prop` in your `sortBy` object (the definiton of the sorting) , but access `var property = o.property` when executing the sort. Thus `a[property]` and `b[property]` are always `undefined`, which causes the sorter to always return `0` and thus, not changing the order of the objects in the array.

Comment: Yes indeed, that was the issue!